# Can't scale bitmap

Tags: kotlin, android-bitmap

What I'm trying to do is to scale a bitmap (three times less).
I have this `code` :

```
val matrix = Matrix()
matrix.postScale(bitmap.width.toFloat() / 3, bitmap.height.toFloat() / 3)

val bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bitmap,
            0, 0,
            bitmap.width, bitmap.height,
            matrix, true)

bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 65, thumbnailStream)
```

But it's end with :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Bitmap.setHasAlpha(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Any help?

Comment: Someone? I can't believe nobody knows how to fix it.

Comment: bitmap can null